# I have to click twice to get JQuery click function to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xc6o26y/). I have a problem; it seems almost random. Whenever I click a div to trigger an animation, I have to click twice to get the animation to fire. A little side note, in the fiddle, the animation isn't functional for some reason, so just assume it takes two clicks to animate each div; which is what I don't want.

HTML

```
<footer>
    <one id="one">
        <p unselectable="on"></p>
    </one>
    <two id="two">
        <p unselectable="on"></p>
    </two>
    <three-info>
    </three-info>
    <three id="three">
        <p unselectable="on"></p>
    </three>
</footer>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#three').click(function () {
        var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
        if (clicks) {
            $("#three").animate({
                marginLeft: $(window).width() - 900 + 'px'
            }, 745, 'linear');
        } else {
            $("#three").animate({
                marginLeft: 0 + 'px'
            }, 800, 'linear');
        }
        $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
        if ($("#two").css("marginLeft") == $(window).width() - 900 + 'px') {
            $("#two").animate({
                marginLeft: 0 + 'px'
            }, 100, 'linear');
            $("#three").animate({
                marginLeft: $(window).width() - 900 + 'px'
            }, 745, 'linear');
        }
        if ($("#one").css("marginLeft") == $(window).width() - 900 + 'px') {
            $("#one").animate({
                marginLeft: 0 + 'px'
            }, 100, 'linear');
            $("#three").animate({
                marginLeft: $(window).width() - 900 + 'px'
            }, 745, 'linear');
        }
    });
    $('#two').click(function () {
        var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
        if (clicks) {
            $("#two").animate({
                marginLeft: $(window).width() - 900 + 'px'
            }, 745, 'linear');
        } else {
            $("#two").animate({
                marginLeft: 0 + 'px'
            }, 700, 'linear');
        }
        $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
        if ($("#three").css("marginLeft") == $(window).width() - 900 + 'px') {
            $("#three").animate({
                marginLeft: 0 + 'px'
            }, 100, 'linear');
            $("#two").animate({
                marginLeft: $(window).width() - 900 + 'px'
            }, 745, 'linear');
        }
        if ($("#one").css("marginLeft") == $(window).width() - 900 + 'px') {
            $("#one").animate({
                marginLeft: 0 + 'px'
            }, 100, 'linear');
            $("#two").animate({
                marginLeft: $(window).width() - 900 + 'px'
            }, 745, 'linear');
        }
    });
    $('#one').click(function () {
        var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
        if (clicks) {
            $("#one").animate({
                marginLeft: $(window).width() - 900 + 'px'
            }, 745, 'linear');
        } else {
            $("#one").animate({
                marginLeft: 0 + 'px'
            }, 700, 'linear');
        }
        $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
        if ($("#two").css("marginLeft") == $(window).width() - 900 + 'px') {
            $("#two").animate({
                marginLeft: 0 + 'px'
            }, 100, 'linear');
            $("#one").animate({
                marginLeft: $(window).width() - 900 + 'px'
            }, 745, 'linear');
        }
        if ($("#three").css("marginLeft") == $(window).width() - 900 + 'px') {
            $("#three").animate({
                marginLeft: 0 + 'px'
            }, 100, 'linear');
            $("#one").animate({
                marginLeft: $(window).width() - 900 + 'px'
            }, 745, 'linear');
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
footer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    overflow: visible !important;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */

/* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
one {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: pink;
    height: 115px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: block;
}
one,two,three {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Raleway", Arial, Helvetica, Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 115px;
}
one:hover {
    background: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 115px;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
two:hover {
    background: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 115px;
    float: left; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
three:hover {
    background: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 115px;
    float: left; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
two {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 115px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: block;
}
three {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 115px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Note your fiddle wasnt working because you didnt tell it to include jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/w1uhv3eg/

Comment: My eyes hurt when looked at your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code requires you to click twice because on the first click your `clicks` data hasn't been set yet so your `else` clause of your if statement happens first

```
//"clicks" will be undefined the first time through
var clicks = $(this).data('clicks'); 
if (clicks) {
   $("#two").animate({marginLeft: $(window).width()-900 +'px'}, 745, 'linear');
} else {
   //so this part gets executed first
   $("#two").animate({marginLeft: 0 +'px'}, 700, 'linear');
}
```

You can either set a data-* attribute or use .data() to set it

```
$("#three").data('clicks',true);
$("#two").data('clicks',true);
$("#one").data('clicks',true);
```

Or

```
<three id="three" data-clicks="1">
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1uhv3eg/2/)

Comment: In that case it'll be `undefined` and `else` part of the code should execute, right?

Comment: Yes, the else part executes the first time through, if you want the true part to execute first then set the data

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the element is first clicked the value of `data-clicks` attribute is `undefined`. You can set this value in HTML by adding `data-clicks="true"` or you can also set the value in Javascript as

```
$('#one, #two, #three').data('clicks', true);
```

I've also optimised your code to make it dry.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/w1uhv3eg/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // To animate the other elements than the clicked one
  function animateOthers(clickedElement, otherElement) {
    otherElement.animate({
      marginLeft: 0 + 'px'
    }, 100, 'linear');
    clickedElement.animate({
      marginLeft: $(window).width() - 900 + 'px'
    }, 745, 'linear');
  }

  // To animate the element that is clicked
  function animate(clicks, first, otherElements) {
    var leftMargin = ($(window).width() - 900) + 'px';

    var left = '0px',
      duration = 800;

    if (clicks) {
      // Update the marginLeft and duration to animate
      left = leftMargin;
      duration = 745;
    }

    // Animate the clicked element
    first.animate({
      marginLeft: left
    }, duration, 'linear');

    // For other elements
    otherElements.forEach(function(v) {
      if ($('#' + v).css('marginLeft') == leftMargin) {
        animateOthers(first, $('#' + v));
      }
    });

    // Update the data-clicks value by negating it
    first.data("clicks", !clicks);
  }

  // Array of all the elements
  var elements = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  // Bind click event on the elements on the array
  $('#' + elements.join(',#')).on('click', function() {
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');

    var clickedElement = $(this).attr('id'),
      otherElements = elements.slice();
    otherElements.splice(elements.indexOf(clickedElement), 1);
    // otherElements is the array of the elements other than the clicked

    animate(clicks, $(this), otherElements);
  });
});
```

```css
footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 115px;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  overflow: visible !important;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE10+ */
  /* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
one {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 115px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: block;
}
one,
two,
three {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Raleway", Arial, Helvetica, Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 115px;
}
one:hover {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 115px;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
two:hover {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 115px;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
three:hover {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 115px;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
two {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 115px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: block;
}
three {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 115px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
  <one id="one" data-clicks="true">
    <p unselectable="on"></p>
  </one>
  <two id="two" data-clicks="true">
    <p unselectable="on"></p>
  </two>
  <three-info></three-info>
  <three id="three" data-clicks="true">
    <p unselectable="on"></p>
  </three>
</footer>
```

Comment: I didn't like the code in the question, so write my own version