# I have two click twice again to fire jquery animation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dt8c2kbf/)

Last time it was purely a javascript problem so I won't post the html. A user said I had to set html "data-clicks" but after refining my code and adding another "else" clause, I now have to click twice again. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900240/i-have-to-click-twice-to-get-jquery-click-function-to-fire) to the last post. The html is the same. I don't quite understand "data-clicks", I did some research but still don't quite understand it.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#three').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
     $("#three").animate({marginLeft: $(window).width()-900 +'px'}, 746, 'linear');
     $("#three-info").css("visibility" , "visible");
     $("#ignore-three").css("visibility" , "visible");
     $("#ignore-three").fadeIn(3000);
  } else {
      if ($("#three").css("marginLeft")=='0px') {
          $("#ignore-three").css("visibility" , "visible");
          $("#ignore-three").fadeIn(3000);
          }
     else {
         $("#three").animate({marginLeft: 0 +'px'}, 700, 'linear');
         $("#ignore-three").css("visibility" , "hidden");
     };
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
   if ($("#two").css("marginLeft")==$(window).width()-900 +'px') {
     $("#ignore-three").css("visibility" , "visible");
     $("#two").animate({marginLeft: 0 +'px'}, 63, 'linear');
     $("#three").animate({marginLeft: $(window).width()-900 +'px'}, 746, 'linear');
     $("#ignore-two").css("visibility" , "hidden");
  }
  if ($("#one").css("marginLeft")==$(window).width()-900 +'px') {
     $("#one").animate({marginLeft: 0 +'px'}, 63, 'linear');
     $("#three").animate({marginLeft: $(window).width()-900 +'px'}, 746, 'linear');
     $("#ignore-one").css("visibility" , "hidden");
  } 
});
$('#two').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
     $("#two").animate({marginLeft: $(window).width()-900 +'px'}, 746, 'linear');
     $("#two-info").css("visibility" , "visible");
     $("#ignore-two").css("visibility" , "visible");
  } else {
      if ($("#two").css("marginLeft")=='0px') {
          $("#ignore-two").css("visibility" , "visible");
          }
     else {
         $("#two").animate({marginLeft: 0 +'px'}, 700, 'linear');
         $("#ignore-two").css("visibility" , "hidden");
     };
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
  if ($("#three").css("marginLeft")==$(window).width()-900 +'px') {
     $("#ignore-two").css("visibility" , "visible");
     $("#three").animate({marginLeft: 0 +'px'}, 63, 'linear');
     $("#two").animate({marginLeft: $(window).width()-900 +'px'}, 746, 'linear');
     $("#ignore-three").css("visibility" , "hidden");
  }
  if ($("#one").css("marginLeft")==$(window).width()-900 +'px') {
     $("#one").animate({marginLeft: 0 +'px'}, 63, 'linear');
     $("#two").animate({marginLeft: $(window).width()-900 +'px'}, 746, 'linear');
     $("#ignore-one").css("visibility" , "hidden");
  }  
});
$('#one').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
     $("#one").animate({marginLeft: $(window).width()-900 +'px'}, 746, 'linear');
     $("#one-info").css("visibility" , "visible");
     $("#ignore-one").css("visibility" , "visible");
  } else {
      if ($("#one").css("marginLeft")=='0px') {
          $("#ignore-one").css("visibility" , "visible");
          }
     else {
         $("#one").animate({marginLeft: 0 +'px'}, 700, 'linear');
         $("#ignore-one").css("visibility" , "hidden");
     };
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
  if ($("#two").css("marginLeft")==$(window).width()-900 +'px') {
     $("#ignore-one").css("visibility" , "visible");
     $("#two").animate({marginLeft: 0 +'px'}, 63, 'linear');
     $("#one").animate({marginLeft: $(window).width()-900 +'px'}, 746, 'linear');
     $("#ignore-two").css("visibility" , "hidden");
  }
  if ($("#three").css("marginLeft")==$(window).width()-900 +'px') {
     $("#three").animate({marginLeft: 0 +'px'}, 63, 'linear');
     $("#one").animate({marginLeft: $(window).width()-900 +'px'}, 746, 'linear');
     $("#ignore-three").css("visibility" , "hidden");
  } 
});
```

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/32900547/2025923

Comment: Yes I did, it worked, but I added another "else" clause which threw everything off again.

Comment: I think its his question only ! :D

Comment: I decided to inject "data-clicks"1"" into the html, but that became obsolete when I added the other else clause.

Comment: @brute_force Yes, and this question sounds similar to that one

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what's causing the problem. Every time I add an "else" clause, randomly, I'll have to double click to get the .animation to fire.

Comment: Try teasing it apart with console.log and see what is going on.

Comment: I think your if statement is backwards. Try making it `if(!clicks){` and see if that fixes it. I'm guessing by default you don't have a truthy data-clicks value so your starting state is a falsey data-clicks so you need to use a ! to invert it.

Comment: still not working. arghh. I hate learning new things.